# RoR: Mark an object complete, save completed_on in other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am creating an action whereby a user can mark homework as complete.

Homework is stored mostly in homework table but homework_student holds the completed_on and a boolean complete attribute:

homework_student.rb

```
 id             :integer          not null, primary key
    #  school_user_id :integer          not null
    #  homework_id    :integer          not null
    #  completed_on   :datetime
    #  created_at     :datetime         not null
    #  updated_at     :datetime         not null
    #  complete       :boolean

belongs_to :homework, :class_name => 'Homework', :foreign_key => :homework_id, dependent: :destroy
```

homework.rb

```
 has_many :homework_students, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent', dependent: :destroy
```

My attempt...

In my show view for homework I want the user to be able to click complete on their homework and to have the date stored in the completed_on attribute in homework_students.

Routes:

```
 resources :homeworks do 
    resources :homework_students do
    member do
      patch :complete
    end
  end
end
```

homeworks_controller.rb:

```
def complete
        @complete_item = Homework.homework_students.update_attribute(:completed_on, Time.now)
    end
```

In my view:

```
<% @homework.homework_students.each do |homework_student| %> 
          <%= link_to "complete", complete_homework_path(:homework_id => @homework, :home_work_students_id => homework_student), method: :patch %> 
          <% end %>
```

I am trying a PATCH method but it is not working. I'm not sure whether it is better to use the boolean attribute for this but i'm not sure how. Homework has many users and each user updates whether they completed or not.

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `homework
```

Much appreciate any guidance.

UPDATE: homeworks_controller.rb

```
        before_action :find_homework, only: [:show, :complete, :edit, :update]
                    #before_action :set_homework, only: [:show]
                    #before_action :set_homework_student, except: [:create]
                    before_action :authenticate_user!

            ....
    def complete
        # Loop over each matching homework_student for the @homework where the id matches and update the completed_on attribute.
        # You need to get the indivual homework_student record and update it. You could do it other ways but this seemed to work for me.
        @homework.homework_students.where(id: params[:home_work_students_id]).each do |homework_student| homework_students.update_attributes(:completed_on => Time.now)
        end
        # Redirect back to the @homework view.
        redirect_to @homework, notice: 'Homework was successfully marked as complete.'        
      end
            ....

          private

                def set_homework_student
                    @homework_students =    HomeworkStudent.find(params[:homework_id])
                end

                def set_homework
                  @homework = @homework_students.homeworks.find(params[:id])
                end


                def homework_params
                    params.require(:homework).permit(:user_id, :id, :school_user_id, :homeworks, :significance, :significance_id, :sig_option, :feedback_request, :subject, :source, :description, :due, :completed_at, homework_students: [:completed_on, :complete], school_user: [:f_name, :s_name])
                end



def find_homework
            @homework = Homework.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

UPDATED ERROR:

```
Error message:

undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: 

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/homeworks_controller.rb:39:in `block in complete'
app/controllers/homeworks_controller.rb:39:in `complete'
Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"OL1vW0BnnJ8TM5lshZWNKisNMrTU2Gp2cY7jYf3T+NRhlx2994q0ndrpehz+vW5unY1EBtSKCHecOJjTDwLHsw==",
 "home_work_students_id"=>"142",
 "homework_id"=>"78",
 "id"=>"78"}
```

VIEW Update

```
 <% @homework.homework_students.each do |homework_student| %>
              <%= link_to "complete", complete_homework_path(@homework, homework_student), method: :patch %> 
              <% end %>
```

Comment: It looks like its from your link_to where you reference homework.id.  should it be @homework.id?  Hard to tell without seeing more code but that variable doesnt seem to be defined anywhere.  If its in your controller it should be an instance variable to access it in your view.  What does your log/stack trace say when you click the complete link?

Comment: Hi, I can't get to the link because the page does not load. I put in @homework.id as follows: <%= link_to "Mark as Complete", complete_homework_homework_student_path(@homework_students, @homework.id), method: :patch %>  and this is the error...No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"homework_students", :homework_id=>nil, :id=>"78"} missing required keys: [:homework_id]...I don't have a homework_students controller, I only have homework controller. I'll post some of the code.

Comment: Move the `member do
      patch :complete
    end` up one block.  You have it nested in the homework_students controller.  Then run `rake routes` to get the proper path. Also watch the params.  @homework_students is nil (and in the wrong order). Chances are you're looping through these in your view so that is likely a local variable `homework_students.id`.  But again, a bit hard to tell.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it doesn't really fix the problem. Sounds like @user3366016 should submit one once the cause has been determined.

Comment: Thanks @user3366016, I did this and now error... No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"homeworks", :format=>78, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]. I updated OP with some controller code. Can post more if needed. Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you check if the route exists by using rake routes? It should be something like complete_homeworks_path.  If yes, then its likely your paramaters you're passing in (the error makes them seem off). What ever you pass in must be defined in the controller action/view then youll have to update the complete action to use those paramaters to make the update.

Comment: Yes the route is complete_homework_path now.

Comment: ok now I can load the view, I click on the link and it says undefined method `homework_students'...coming from complete action: def complete
  @complete_item = @homework.homework_students.update_attribute(:completed_on, Time.now)
 end

Comment: But to get there I had to change in view to <%= link_to "Mark as Complete", complete_homework_path(@homework.id), method: :patch %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mocked this version up based on our comments and it works on my end although it may not be the best approach.  You may want to watch [this video from Mackenzie Child](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd1Vn-Wvy2w) who uses ajax to make this type of update on his todo app (mark things as complete, etc).

In your routes.rb

```
resources :homeworks do 
    member do
      patch :complete
    end
    resources :homework_students
end
```

In your homework_controller.rb

```
 def complete
    # Loop over each matching homework_student for the @homework where the id matches and update the completed_on attribute.
    # You need to get the indivual homework_student record and update it. You could do it other ways but this seemed to work for me.
    @homework.homework_students.where(id: params[:home_work_students_id]).each do |homework_student|
      homework_student.update_attributes(:completed_on => Time.now)
    end
    # Redirect back to the @homework view.
    redirect_to @homework, notice: 'Homework was successfully marked as complete.'        
  end
```

`before_action :set_homework, only: [:show, :complete]`

In your homework show.html.erb

```
# This assumes you are looping over the @homework.homework_students in your view to create a link for each homework_student record and that will give you access to the homework_student local variable.
<%= link_to "complete", complete_homework_path(:homework_id => @homework, :home_work_students_id => homework_student), method: :patch %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I still get undefined local variable or method `homework_student' after trying your answer. The table name is homework_students. I'm overlooking something in my controller or view pretty basic. I actually was working off the video.

Comment: I really appreciate the time, i think i nearly have it...the model associations are right, i'm missing something simple.

Comment: Np.  Here you say homework_student is undefined but above you say homework_students.  Can you post the full error as an update to your question and the view code?

Comment: You have to update the attributes for a single homework_student otherwise you could get that error.  I have some comments in the controller above to help explain.

Comment: The issue is in your view. Are you looping over your `@homework.homewprk_students.each do |homework_student| <%= link_to "complete", complete_homework_path(@homework, homework_student), method: :patch %> end

Comment: Ok, the view is fixed, now the error is in the complete action. undefined method `homework_students' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I have checked DB and the record is correct in the error, format '142' is the homework_student id and '78' is the homework_id. Nearly there....:/

Comment: Updated view snippet to help set the params properly and controller before action to set the @homework, thats the nil class error.

Comment: Thanks, I updated OP to include new error on "update_attributes" + private settings in controller so you can see find_homework too. set_homework does not appear to work, when i leave set homework in it comes back with "Couldn't find HomeworkStudent with 'id'="...I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Co2 looks like you might have a typo in your controller complete action.  In the block make the `homework_students.update_attr...` singular instead of plural. Remove the s from `homework_students` so that it uses the local variable of the block. we can chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128806/discussion-between-user3366016-and-co2