# RoR: Filtering user options in for_each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreach, filter

I am trying to filter options for complete by school_user_id in my view. This follows on from this question: [RoR: Mark an object complete, save completed_on in other model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752826/ror-mark-an-object-complete-save-completed-on-in-other-model/40754170?noredirect=1#comment68757558_40754170)

So a student is able to mark a piece of homework complete. But in the view it is rendering 4 complete options because 4 school_users are associated with that piece of homework. I am trying to filter so that only the current school_user's complete option is available.

User and School_user have a one to one relationship.

In my view (this does not work and renders nothing, if where statement removed renders 4 complete options)

homeworks/show.html.erb

```
<% @homework.homework_students.where(school_user_id: current_user.id).each do |homework_student| %> 
 <%= link_to "complete", complete_homework_path(:homework_id => @homework, :home_work_students_id => homework_student), method: :patch %> 
<% end %>
```

Models:

school_user.rb

```
has_many :homework_students, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent'
has_many :homeworks, :class_name => 'Homework'
```

homework_student.rb

```
has_many :homework_ratings, :class_name => 'HomeworkRating'
belongs_to :homework, :class_name => 'Homework', :foreign_key => :homework_id, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :school_user, :class_name => 'SchoolUser', :foreign_key => :school_user_id
```

homework.rb

```
has_many :homework_students, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent', dependent: :destroy 
belongs_to :school_user, :class_name => 'SchoolUser', :foreign_key => :school_user_id
```

If I was filtering else where I would do something like this:

```
<% if homework.school_user.user_id == current_user.id %>
```

From the rails console:

```
irb(main):002:0> search = HomeworkStudent.find(142) 
HomeworkStudent Load (0.5ms) SELECT `homework_students`.* FROM `homework_students` WHERE `homework_students`.`id` = 142 LIMIT 1 
=> #<HomeworkStudent id: 142, school_user_id: 10001, homework_id: 78, completed_on: "2016-11-23 18:05:34", created_at: "2016-11-22 00:27:24", updated_at: "2016-11-23 18:05:34", completed: nil>
```

As you can see school_user_id is there. It's just a case of filtering out the other completes which are for other users with that homework. But I don't know how to do this with for_each.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.Happy to provide more code/info if needed.

UPDATE:

```
<% @homework.homework_students.joins(:school_user).where(school‌​_user: { user_id: current_user.id }).each do |homework_student| %>
```

Error

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'school‌​_user.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `homework_students`.* FROM `homework_students` INNER JOIN `school_users` ON `school_users`.`id` = `homework_students`.`school_user_id` WHERE `homework_students`.`homework_id` = 78 AND `school‌​_user`.`user_id` = 1
```

Comment: This `, :class_name => 'SchoolUser', :foreign_key => :school_user_id` is redundant, Rails can figure out this for you. Same applies to `:homework` mapping in part of `foreign_key`, and to `class_name` in the rest of mappings.

Comment: `.where(school_user_id: current_user.id)` should be `.where(school_user: current_user)`

Comment: Is `current_user` an instance of `SchoolUser` class?

Comment: Thanks, I don't think so, I think it's an instance of user. User_id is also in school_users model though. I tried above. Same result, renders nothing. Everything goes through school user, thus <% if homework.school_user.user_id == current_user.id %>, this works in that example.

Comment: When debugging, replace `link_to` with debug output, e.g. `<%= current_user.id %>, <%= homework_student.inspect %>` and post your output.

Comment: Does `@homework.homework_students.joins(:school_user).where(school_user: { user_id: current_user.id })` work?

Comment: Thanks, posted update in OP, using your code and the error

Comment: Above <%= current_user.id %> comes back as 1, school_user is 10001, homework_student.inspect comes back as undefined method

Comment: Try .joins(:school_user**s**)

Comment: Thanks, This error...Association named 'school_users' was not found on HomeworkStudent; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Try .where(school‌​_user**s**:

Comment: Pal, I owe you one!! Thank you so much, that works. :)

Comment: @philpirozhkov not sure if this is most efficient way but at least it works!

Comment: How do I mark your comment as right answer??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128889/discussion-between-phil-pirozhkov-and-co2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
@homework.homework_students.joins(:school_user).where(school‌​_users: { user_id: current_user.id }).each
```